young silver maple with severe bark wound
We planted a silver maple last year and used soft loop-style stakes to help it grow straight. However, it developed a large (over 60%) wound on its 1 year old trunk (which is only @ 2" in diameter). The top has stopped growing and is not getting nutrients but there are 3 strong suckers at the bottom which are healthy and green. The wound is located about 3" from the base, so very low down with the deepest wound on the left side.
Our county extension office recommended we cut the ENTIRE tree down below the wound, allow the suckers to continue growing thru next year and them pick one to be the new "tree'. But I cannot find any other info which recommends this dramatic approach and the wound is quite low so it would be a 3" stump as we go into winter. I am afraid of further traumatizing the tree and everything I read says not to remove more than 20% of leaves at a time.
This tree was planted in memoriam for someone and means so much to us that I really want it to live but I am afraid to use the bypass loppers on the whole trunk when I literally can't find one other expert who recommends this? Please advise as it is now September and I want to make the right decision before the cold Midwest (zone 5) winter hits. Thank you!





pictures please

if you need a better angle please let me know. ANY help you can give is grealy appreciated!

In any case, put a fence around it (maybe a metallic net just few inches from trunk). I think some animals (large mammal) did it to sucks sap.

i will do that immediately. Thank you !! Are you suggesting that an animal did this damage and not the loops? They were actually really loose and constantly slipping down so not extremely taut. I just assumed that improper staking was the cause??

@GiacomoCatenazzi has it with animals, not staking. But are you committed to keeping this oak-sized tree a yard or two from the fence?

yes, we can actually move the fence out 4-5 feet if needed. It is probably about 9 feet away from the fence now but our property line extends beyond this so if necessary we can move it back if you think that best. What kind of animals would do this sort of damage?

Would a groundhog do that kind of damage? I have seen one in the neighborhood which is a bit weird because , while there are wooded areas nearby, we are definitely not in a rural setting. Just finished caging the whole thing in! Thank you all for your contined advice!!

or completely remove the fence if necessary. It was there when we bought the house  but the actual lot is about 12 feet past where the tree currently is

Hello @geoffsimmons, and welcome to the site!  I've edited your question to put the explanation first and added paragraph breaks, I hope you don't mind.  Good luck with the tree!

ok thank you @MarkM

First thing you should establish is the cause of the damage. No point in going to a lot of work on the suckers if the same thing will happen again.
Common causes of this kind of damage are:

damaged before or during planting by the trunk being banged against a hard object
rabbits or mice (usually during the winter)
lawnmowers

Solutions to this are:

wrap the tree with plastic tree trunk protectors. You can get them at hardware stores.  They are a strip of plastic with holes that you wrap around the trunk in the fall and remove in the spring
roll back the grass for two feet around the trunk and mulch so there is no need to get a mower close

As far as the damage I have been proven wrong before when I looked at trees with bark damage and gave an opinion that they were done for.  However the fact the leaves on the top are all dead and the suckers are doing fine leads me to suggest that you wait till next spring.  If the main trunk does not leaf out then you should follow the advice of the extension office to cut it down to the area of the cut and select one sucker as the new lead.  This is good advice!  Silver maples are vigorous and I see no reason why with some care it will be just fine.

Thank you @kevinskio !! Great advice !! I will definitely wrap the tree today. We don't use a power mower and the area is mulched but I agree with your advice that I should have created an even wider berth. I am so grateful for your help!!

Question ! Do I want to surround the entire trunk AND sucker or do I find one that is more flush with the trunk? If flush, are the suckers pulled through the holes or am I just setting myself up for repeat disaster? how high up the trunk should I go? I realize these are Tree 101 questions but it's honestly my first tree and I aready feel awful about missing the signs until it was too late. Just want to be absolutely correct. Thanks so much !

@geoffsimmons  Put at least one wrap around the main trunk and at least one around the sucker that is your backup to become the main trunk at least as high as the snow lies in winter.  In many places that would six to twelve inches.  One type of wrap is about 18" tall and that should do the job nicely.  The wrap goes around the suckers and the main trunk.  Do not put the suckers through the holes as this could damage the bark.

Wow. thank you so much for the detailed information . I will implement your methods immediately and hopefully , come spring have good results to share. You are exceptionally patient and knowledgeable. Im quite grateful
